# to_json skips attributes with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

hi i am new to ruby on rails and using mongoid with rails.
when i try to convert an mongoid object into json the attributes with nil values are skipped.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :019 >@task
 => #<Task _id: 4e707635c7b4700ce3000004, _type: "Task", created_at: 2011-09-14     09:39:01 UTC, updated_at: 2011-09-14 09:39:01 UTC, due_date: nil, is_completed: false, assignee_id: nil, description: "hi remind this ", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4e4d1aeac7b4700c6e000096'), item_id: BSON::ObjectId('4e53585fc7b4701082000002')>  

@task.to_json(:only=>[:due_date])
=> "{}"
```

is there any way to get like `"{\"due_date\":\"null\"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to override the retrieval of `due_date`.

Try this in your model:

```
def due_date
  real_value = self[:due_date]
  return real_value unless real_value.nil?
  return "null"
end
```

Comment: i have tried with this code.when i call 'due_date' directly i am getting 'null' if 'due_date' nil but not when invoking json method to the same object.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mmm, it worked for me. A work around, use: ':methods => :due_date' and ':except=> :due_date' in your json options